# Angular array Push not refreshing data on UI

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I've a object of arrays as following:

```
 $scope.orderList = {
      newOrders: [],
      pendingOrders: [],
      processedOrders: []
 }
```

these arrays ie  `newOrders` are collection of object `order` which has a child object `user`.

Each array is displaying data in different table using `ng-repeat` and displaying `username` on UI . On click  I want to push an object from `newOrders` array to `pendingOrders` array.

this is how I'm doing.

```
$scope.changeOrderStatus=function(orderToUpdate, statusId){
     orderToUpdate.status=statusId;

    // removing order from newOrder array
    var index = $scope.orderList.newOrders.indexOf(orderToUpdate);
    $scope.orderList.newOrders.splice(index, 1);

    // working fine upto this point         

    // but when I push it to "pendingOrders" like below, I lose "User" 
    $scope.orderList.pendingOrders.push(orderToUpdate);    
});
```

Issue is `order` object properties are diplayed on UI. but its child object `user` doesnt show its property `username` on UI.

I hope I made my problem clear enough.

Comment: Where's your HTML code and what's the object you're passing into `$scope.orderList.pendingOrders.push(orderToUpdate);`, also can you provide some outputs or logs so we can better understand your problem?

Comment: Thanks Philip for replying.  I've shorted out. I was making a round trip  to server before pushing and that changed the "order" object.